# Cannot reset or replace default font in the Android application

Tags: android, android-typeface

I set the default font on my application, and now that I don't think it fits well on the UI, I wanted to reset it. But I don't know how to reset it.

Here are the codes, and solutions to this problem will be well appreciated.

(1) I first created a FontOverride class to replace the default font with a new one.

```
public class FontsOverride {
public static void setDefaultFont(Context context, String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName, final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

(2) And I created another class named AppConfig which controls the overall configuration of the application.

```
    public class AppConfig extends android.app.Application {

    public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://marshall.hostzi.com/Gruppo/";
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://marshall.hostzi.com/Gruppo/";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "fonts/Galderglynn.ttf");
    }
}
```

(3) And finally here's the style.xml file. There is one item named monospace so that the monospace will be replaced by Ganderglynn.ttf programatically.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

I tried switching Galderglynn.ttf file with another one, but it wouldn't work, and the fonts are still in Galderglynn font.

EDIT here's the part of Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<application
    android:name="com.marshall.gruppo.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add another font in yourapp/src/main/assets/fonts/
like this:(Sorry, i can't post image now)

And next steps, change your fontPath in config

```
public class AppConfig extends android.app.Application {

    public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://marshall.hostzi.com/Gruppo/";
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://marshall.hostzi.com/Gruppo/";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf");
    }
}
```

Finally, I recommend some awesome libs to change default font like Calligraphy: https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already tried that way.. that wouldn't work.

Comment: Check in your android manifest, is AppTheme was using, or another them instead?

Comment: I just edited and uploaded the part of my Androidmanifest.xml. I was using the style defined in the style.xml.

Comment: Try to add 'FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf");' in onCreate in your com.marshall.gruppo.app.AppController instead of AppConfig

Comment: Hmm very strange.. I just tried that way and it didn't work either.

Comment: I think this is because the default monospace font source itself was replaced with the new one.

Comment: I think you should try to find in your project with keyword "Galderglynn", and replace all with anotherFont name. May be you call this function in somewhere. If not, hm... very strange!

Comment: Or you try to change with sans like this
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>

and in your application
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS", "fonts/anotherFont.ttf");
    }